# WooCommerce not saving the SKU value

Tags: woocommerce

I note that in Woocommerce, in my list of products, some products do not show an SKU number. When I edit the product, and go under Inventory, the SKU is blank. When I type in the correct SKU and update the product and then go back under Inventory, the SKU is blank again. I.e., the SKU is not getting saved. Any suggestions why this behavior is happening and any way to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked that the SKU is not being repeated?. Sometimes when that happens is because that SKU already exists in other product.

Comment: Yes, I discovered I had some duplicate SKU's. Deleting the duplicate items solved the problem. Thanks for responding.